# How to give write rights of a file to a group

Tags: files, permissions, chmod

I want to make a folder writable by any user in a group
So I first create a new group like this:

```
sudo groupadd newGroup
```

then I add user1 and user2 in this group like:

```
sudo usermod -a -G newGroup user1
sudo usermod -a -G newGroup user2
```

I check that these users are in the group with:

```
getent group newGroup
```

Then in my folder I give ownership to the group like:

```
sudo chown :newGroup myfile
```

and change permission rights to 770 so anyone in the group can write the folder with

```
sudo chmod 770 myfile
```

But when I try to open the folder with user2 that is in the group I cannot! I can open it only with user1 which is the user that owns the file.
What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Ls la results of the file

```
$ ls -la | grep myfile
-rwxrwx---  1 user1              newGroup       3819 Jan 16 10:21 myfile
```

**EDIT 2**

I simply needed to logout and login on order the effects to take place.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -la` for this file?

Comment: I just posted them

Comment: and the permissions of the previous folder?

Comment: what do you mean with previous folder?

Comment: the folder containing this file

Comment: ok the file is in a folder owned by root:root

Comment: Did user2 logout and login so that group changes took effect (or used `newgrp`, etc.?)

Comment: wow this was it - I simply needed to logout and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users (user1 and user2 in your example) need to logout and login again, only then will their inclusion to the new group become effective.

A process P (such as a shell) that belongs to user U and that is a member of, say, groups G1 and G2 (as displayed by `id`) will **not** be affected by any changes to this arrangement (e.g. via `usermod` or similar). Specifically, if you add user U to group G3, then process P will not notice. Likewise, if you remove group G2, P will not notice as well. This applies also to child processes since identity attributes are inherited; so if process P1 is launched for user U while U is member of G1 and G2, and U is removed from G2, and then P1 forks P2, then P2 will still be in G1 and G2. This is why user U must logout and login again, because identity attributes are set by programs like `login`.

Comment: I have already edited my question to show that this was the solution to my problem thanks to the comment from @muru I will accept your answer but should muru post an answer stating this solution I will accept his

Comment: @MichailN Feel free to reassign the accepted answer. On top of telling what to do I took the liberty to provide an explanation for the observed behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check the permission of path where you created the new folder by below path.

```
ls -ld .
```

If Path where new folder exsists doesnt have group permission to access but you have given necessary permission to new folder. its of no use.

Since first group users should be able to access the path of new folder. Then they should enter  new folder directory.

Give atleast 750 to path where new folder exsists. so group users will be able to enter it to the path